# MySQL - First row is RANDOM, all others are sorted DESC (How To)

Tags: mysql

I have a complex MySQL query, and I want **the first row of the result to be a random row of the query result, and all following rows to be ordered by date, desc**.

I would like this to be done without having to use UNION or having to call mysql_query() twice. I use PHP as scripting language.

Here is a question similar to mines, but the answers there don't work for my particular case:
[mysql query to select one specific row and another random row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958366/mysql-query-to-select-one-specific-row-and-another-random-row)

So, my question is if it can be done through ORDER BY or any other method.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using a scripting language or does this need to be pure MySQL?

Comment: using two sql is the better options

Comment: @liquorvicar, I use PHP as scripting language. However, the random result would be from the whole table (or a set of it), not just a random row of the "LIMIT 10" I took from the ordered result. Thank you.

Comment: And why the restinkion of not using `UNION`?

Comment: @ypercube - Because I think that UNION is equivalent two 2 queries, so I wanted to be sure that it isn't possible with just 1 query.

Comment: UNION is more optimal than two queries as you still avoid a round trip to the database. I can't see any better way to do it. You might even want to do two completely separate queries as getting a random result in MySQL is not very optimal anyway: http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/

Comment: a query with a UNION is one query not two. Just a bit more complex than one without. If you use `UNION ALL` - which seems plausible here - should be good for efficiency.

Comment: @liquorvicar - Thank you for referring that page. I read that one very long ago, and I use those methods often. However, I restrict rows where date is not older than 2 days, so the RAND() should just sort those "little" rows, in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND()) t1, (SELECT @s:= NULL) t2
    ORDER BY @s:=IF(@s IS NULL, 0, 1), date DESC
```

---

```
SELECT t1.* FROM
  table t1,
  (SELECT @rand_id:=id FROM (SELECT id FROM actor ORDER BY RAND()) t LIMIT 1) t2
    ORDER BY IF(t1.id = @rand_id, 0, 1), date DESC
```

Comment: So that I may test it properly, I would like to understand the query first. Could you please explain to me what are these and what they do? "SELECT @s:= NULL" and "ORDER BY @s:=IF(@s IS NULL, 0, 1)". Thank you very much!

Comment: "SELECT @s:= NULL" - we set user variable, the same as SET @s:= NULL

Comment: "ORDER BY @s:=IF(@s IS NULL, 0, 1)" - try to comment ORDER BY clause and add '@s:=IF(@s IS NULL, 0, 1)' to the main query - 'SELECT t1.*, @s:=IF(@s IS NULL, 0, 1) FROM ...', and you will see what is happening.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that, but I still don't understand how the ORDER BY works there. You are changing @s to 1 if @s is NULL, right? What's the point of it? Thank you.

Comment: I tested. @s is 0 in the first time, 1 in all the other times. I also tested in a real table, but the query seems TOO slow. It took 5 seconds for 3000 rows, and (at least in phpMyAdmin) it died in a table with 14000 rows. But the result was something that I wanted, yes. :) Thank you once more.

Comment: ORDER BY RAND() is slow. Try to add INDEX on `date` column.

Comment: Yeah, I have INDEX there. But the simple query with "ORDER BY RAND() "or with "ORDER BY date" doesn't take more than 1 second. I understood your query completely, and what it does, but I'm not sure why yours is slower. Maybe because ORDER BY is checking the IF statement too often? No clue.

Comment: I think because it is a trick, and no indexes are used when sorting.

Comment: OK, I have one more solution. Have a look at the answer.

Comment: I don't understand why I got a downvote in my question, btw. I think it was a decent question.

Comment: Maybe because it is not trivial question. But I found this interesting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, or at least, not trivially. Thing in terms of sets - you're asking the database for two conflicting things - one set, ordered randomly, and another set ordered by date etc. In order to get the result you want, you'll have to compose two sets together. You could encapsulate this inside a stored procedure, if you only want to make a single call to the database.

**EDIT**

A view could also encapsulate this logic, if stored procedures (or functions) are available for some reason.

Comment: I understand the problem here, and I thought it could be conflicting, yes. I just wanted to be sure that there wasn't a way to do that :) Thank you for your answer.